# Word for a false definition used for comedic effect

Tags: single-word-requests, humor

Is there a word for a false definition given in jest?

I don't know if such a word exists, but I'm interested to know it if it does.

An example of what I mean would be:

> *Politics* - a latin word stemming from
>   *Poli-* — meaning many
>   *Ticks* — meaning blood-sucking butt lumps

Or this snippet about oil:

> ALL - noun. A petroleum-based lubricant.
>   Usage: "I sure hope my brother from Georgia puts *all* in my pickup truck."

Comment: I don't know if there's a word for this but you just described the premise for the game *Balderdash* :)

Comment: The term found when listing funny pretend definitions was *Daffy-nitions*. No doubt copyrighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think both of your examples are [homophonic puns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pun#Typology) because the joke comes from the how part or all of a word sounds similar to another word, and the words are not synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a single word answer, but the process has a whole dictionary devoted to it called the *Uxbridge English Dictionary* which is also a game in the spoof BBC Radio 4 panel show *I'm Sorry I Haven't a Clue*.

Two definitions picked randomly from an online version ([link here](http://www.alspcs.com)):

- **Handicap**. A very convenient hat
- **Hijack**. A young man under the influence of narcotics

And, of course, the dictionary is available on [amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0007263937).

Perhaps we should coin the new term "Uxbridge-ing".

Comment: Plus the famous "countryside = to kill Piers Morgan"

Answer (score 1):

They're sometimes called daffynitions, although that word makes me grind my teeth when I hear it. The inverse, by the way, is called a sniglet.

Comment: I know. I **HATE** ducks.